# How to avoid npm build node.js packages every time when creating a Docker image via Circle CI?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, amazon-ecs, circleci

I deploy my Node.Js app via `AWS ECS Docker` container using `Circle CI`.

However, each time I build a new image it runs `npm build` (because it's in my `Dockerfile`) and downloads and builds all the `node` modules again every time. Then it uploads a new image to the AWS ECS repository.

As my environment stays the same I don't want it to build those packages every time. So do you think it is possible for Docker to actually update an existing image rather than building a new one from scratch with all the modules every time? Is this generally a good practice?

I was thinking the following workflow:

1. Check if there are any new Node packages compared to the previous image
2. If yes, run `npm build`
3. If not, just keep the old `node_modules` folder, don't run build and simply update the code
4. Deploy

What would be the best way to do that?

Here's my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:12.18.0-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
COPY package.json package-lock.json* ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm install pm2 -g
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "ecosystem.config.js"]
```

My `Circle CI` workflow (from the `./circleci/config.yml`):

```
workflows:
  version: 2.1
  test:
    jobs:
      - test
      - aws-ecr/build-and-push-image:
          create-repo: true
          no-output-timeout: 10m
          repo: 'stage-instance'
```

Answer (score 3):

Move the `COPY . .` line after the `RUN npm install` line.

The way Docker's layer caching works, it will skip re-running a `RUN` line if it knows that it's already run it.  So given this Dockerfile fragment:

```sh
FROM node:12.18.0-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json* ./
RUN npm install
```

Docker keeps track of the hashes of the files it `COPY`s in.  When it gets to the `RUN` line, if the image up to this point is identical to one it's previously built, it will also skip over the `RUN` line.

If you have `COPY . .` first, then if *any* file in your source tree changes, it will invalidate the layer cache for everything afterwards.  If you only copy `package.json` and the lock file first, then `npm install` only gets re-run if either of those two files change.

(CircleCI may or may not perform the same layer caching, but "install dependencies, then copy the application in" is a typical Docker-level optimization.)